# Can PowerBuilder 2017 be set to display line numbers?

Tags: line-numbers, powerbuilder-2017

I have recently upgraded from Powerbuilder 12.5 to PowerBuilder 2017. I know that the current line number (and column) is given at the bottom of the screen but can the line numbers be given next to each line?

Various Powerbuilder settings, looking on the net, and finding some useless answers.

```
IF X <> Y THEN
X = Y
END IF
```

I would rather see:

```
10 IF X <> Y THEN
20 X = Y
30 END IF
```

Answer (score 1):

Showing line numbers in editor like you describe is not possible. The built-in editor is what we've had since the beginning.

Maybe with some C++ coding and PBNI it could happen not sure.

Comment: Thanks for an answer anyway.